# Nginx proxy_pass hierarchy

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running nginx in docker with a asp.net web-service.
If I write my conf like this, I can't get to e.g. http://localhost/order-service/api
This results in "The resource you have requested cannot be found".
The /hubs endpoint is working.

```
upstream order-service {
    server order-service:5048;
}

# HTTP
server {
    listen        80;

    location = /order-service/hubs {
        proxy_pass http://order-service/hubs;
        ...
    }

    location /order-service {
        proxy_pass http://order-service;
        ...
    }
}
```

If I change it to:

```
upstream order-service {
    server order-service:5048;
}

# HTTP
server {
    listen        80;

    location = /order-service/hubs {
        proxy_pass http://order-service/hubs;
        ...
    }

    location /order-service/api {        <--- here is the change!!!
        proxy_pass http://order-service;
        ...
    }
}
```

I can get the api with http:/localhost/order-service

But I have other urls like order-service/ui and order-service/settings.
What must I use to lead all request to order-service but order-service/hubs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two expressions:

```
location /order-service/ {
    proxy_pass http://order-service;
}
```

And:

```
location /order-service/ {
    proxy_pass http://order-service/;
}
```

will generate totally different results.

In the first case, the request `/order-service/api` will be proxied upstream as:

```
http://order-service/order-service/api
```

In the second case, the same request will be translated into:

```
http://order-service/api
```

Looking at your `location = /order-service/hubs` block, you probably need the second case.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I made a mistake in the post. It's not "porxy_pass /order-service/" but "proxy_pass /order-service". I will modify my question. And btw /order-service/hubs is working. But I want all other endpoints resolved be the second match.

Comment: The solution is to write both the location and the proxy_pass with the trailing '/'.

Comment: Correct. And if you do that, you probably no longer need the `location = /order-service/hubs` block.